# SpagoBI integration with Spring mvc web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spagobi

We have a Spring mvc web application, in which we are trying to integrate spagobi. We have downloaded SpagoBISDK.war file and added in build path of web application. Some things are not clear yet:

1. We have added SpagoBISDK.war in build path of web application. Do we need any other file?
2. How can we integrate spagoBI with our Spring mvc web app?